# where can I find good erlang reference for "BIFs"?

Tags: erlang

I have Programming Erlang book already and I use http://www.erlang.org/ site.
But I can't find good reference site for BIFs and modules like **lists:duplicate**.
I found brief explanation from the end of Programming Erlang book but I need more ;( (about parameters, example code.. etc)

anybody can help me out about this?
thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about [this page](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man_index.html) on the Erlang website?  For example, you can find documentation for the `lists` module [here](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/lists.html).

Comment: Lovely! I tried to find out that page but I finally failed and asked here. thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

The [erlang module documentation](http://erlang.org/doc/man/erlang.html) notes BIFs, and notes which can appear in guards.  If you've installed the manpages you can also view the erlang module with  `erl -man erlang`.

Answer (score 2):

late update: Aug 09

this is kind of like Railsapi.com

http://erlapi.prepor.ru/docs/

http://groups.google.com/group/erlang-programming/browse_frm/thread/1e5bcaf304ef249f/1b3d0d676603a81d?lnk=gst&q=erlapi#

source:

http://github.com/prepor/erlapi-static/tree/master

---

also:

http://erldocs.com/otp_src_R13B/

http://www.gotapi.com/erlang

http://www.dpawson.co.uk/erlang/